# python error login with imap even enabled from gmail

Tags: python, python-3.x, gmail, imap

iam trying to use a imap with python but iam getting error every time, i followed all steps to active imap from gmail and unlock captcha but after the firt run iam getting this error pls help already thanks

```
raise self.error(dat[-1])
imaplib.error: b'[AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)'
```

after the gmail i got a Alerte security from gmail and all acces from imap is blocked

the code used `

```
 # Importing libraries 
import imaplib, email 

    user = 'USER_EMAIL_ADDRESS'
    password = 'USER_PASSWORD'
    imap_url = 'imap.gmail.com'
    
    # Function to get email content part i.e its body part 
    def get_body(msg): 
        if msg.is_multipart(): 
            return get_body(msg.get_payload(0)) 
        else: 
            return msg.get_payload(None, True) 
    
    # Function to search for a key value pair 
    def search(key, value, con): 
        result, data = con.search(None, key, '"{}"'.format(value)) 
        return data 
    
    # Function to get the list of emails under this label 
    def get_emails(result_bytes): 
        msgs = [] # all the email data are pushed inside an array 
        for num in result_bytes[0].split(): 
            typ, data = con.fetch(num, '(RFC822)') 
            msgs.append(data) 
    
        return msgs 
    
    # this is done to make SSL connnection with GMAIL 
    con = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_url) 
    
    # logging the user in 
    con.login(user, password) 
    
    # calling function to check for email under this label 
    con.select('Inbox') 
    
    # fetching emails from this user "tu**h*****1@gmail.com" 
    msgs = get_emails(search('FROM', 'MY_ANOTHER_GMAIL_ADDRESS', con)) 
    
    # Uncomment this to see what actually comes as data 
    # print(msgs) 
    
    
    # Finding the required content from our msgs 
    # User can make custom changes in this part to 
    # fetch the required content he / she needs 
    
    # printing them by the order they are displayed in your gmail 
    for msg in msgs[::-1]: 
        for sent in msg: 
            if type(sent) is tuple: 
    
                # encoding set as utf-8 
                content = str(sent[1], 'utf-8') 
                data = str(content) 
    
                # Handling errors related to unicodenecode 
                try: 
                    indexstart = data.find("ltr") 
                    data2 = data[indexstart + 5: len(data)] 
                    indexend = data2.find("</div>") 
    
                    # printtng the required content which we need 
                    # to extract from our email i.e our body 
                    print(data2[0: indexend]) 
    
                except UnicodeEncodeError as e: 
                    pass


'
```

Comment: If you are running this on a cloud host or the like, this will likely never work without implementing OAuth (or maybe app specific passwords).  Google's account security appears to be set up to only allow logins from likely end user hosts.

If you're running it on your personal machine (that you also log in from), you will have to activate the reduced security setting, generate an app specific password, or implement OAuth.

Comment: it was fixed after active the reduced security thank you soo mucch bro @Max  you helped me....so for that must first active the imap and unlock catpcha and reduced security setting....

Comment: I will change to an answer since this helped you.

Comment: @Max you deserved it it was the lost step...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running this on a cloud host or the like, this will likely never work without implementing OAuth authentication (or maybe app specific passwords).

Google's account security appears to be set up to only allow logins from likely end-user hosts. If you're running it on your personal machine (that you also log in from), you will have to activate the reduced security setting, generate an app specific password, or implement OAuth.